# How to plot an array as a heatmap timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to create a sns heatmap where each rows represents one array entry.
My array looks like:

```
arr = [[a, b, c], [b, c, d], [e, f, g]]
```

I have a dictionary of colors which attributes a color to each entry. I created another array using these two arrays such that it contains the color order to be ploted (i.e. :

```
col = [[c0, c1, c2], [c1, c2, c3], [c4, c5, c6]]
```

where c0,1.. are all hex colour codes. Is there any way to make this into a heatmap?

Answer (score 2):

`col` already *is* a heatmap. Unfortunately, matplotlib cannot directly plot hex colors as image, so you need to convert to rgb first.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


col = [["#" + "".join(np.random.choice(list("0123456789abcdef"),6))
                for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]


col = np.array(col)
img = mcolors.to_rgba_array(col.flatten()).reshape(*col.shape, 4)

plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `cmap` parameter do the job. [(doc)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html). You can define your own palette with  `color_palettes` method [(doc)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

Here, I make match the `0` as the first element of your color list,  `1` as the 2nd element of your color list and so on.

Here the code:

```
# import modules
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Init seaborn
sns.set()

# Your data as decimal array
col = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

# Your custum color palette
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71",  "#30095e"]

# Draw heatmap with the custom palette color
ax = sns.heatmap(col, cmap=sns.color_palette(flatui))

# Show graph
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked for a small sample but once I use a bigger dataset I have this:
IndexError: Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input (got (25, 1) and (25,)) even though the list format is the same

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Hard to know with just this. What line is rising the error? Have you an example to reproduce the error?